# Labeling equations and math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, labels

I have to write the equation shown below in Latex and I am using

```
{\textbf{q}=($\mu$  $_1$ $\mu$  $_2$ ... $\mu$  $_{n-2}$
$\mu$ $_n$ )\textsuperscript{T}}
```

and it comes OK.

[image]

However, I need to label the equation and I am using

```
\begin{equation}{\textbf{q}=($\mu$  $_1$ $\mu$  $_2$ ... $\mu$  
$_{n-2}$     $\mu$ $_n$ )\textsuperscript{T}}  \label{2} \end{equation}
```

but I am getting errors stating that there is a missing } and that math mode should end with $$.

Also how can the equation below be written using Latex:

[image]

Comment: In `equation` there mustn't be  `$` inside ;-)

Comment: please can you see the last line of the question since I have a problem with another equation

Comment: in your first equation, you should be using `\mathbf` rather than `\textbf`.

Comment: thanks, can you help me with the second equation?

Comment: for your second equation, you already know how to make a letter bold.  there are commands `\log` and `\exp` for those function names. `\sum` for the sum.  you know how to produce sub and superscripts; limits are done the same way.  since braces are special to latex, to get printed ones, use `\{` and `\}`.  is this enough help?

Comment: @user1930901 please stop adding questions to this question.  if your first question(s) have been answered, mark an answer as accepted and post a new question for your matrix.  you should also be aware that this community discourages "please do this for me" questions.  you haven't shown any attempts to typeset the followup questions for yourself.

Comment: I have tried the first equation but I am really new to Latex and an equation is taking me a lot of time and I am not asking anyone to do my assignment, this is just plain formatting

Comment: @user1930901 Rather than using `\mathbf{q}` I would think of *what* is that `q`. If it's a vector, the logic would be to input `\vec{q}` and then redefine `\vec` to give bold letters (by default it places an small arrow above the letter). In any case, you should change your name to something more telling than user1930901 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example, how this can be typeset:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\transpose}{\mathrm{T}}
\newcommand*{\vc}[1]{\mathhbf{#1}}
% \vec and \vector are already defined

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{q-def}
  \vc{q} = (\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_{n-1}, \mu_{n})^\transpose
\end{equation}
Equation~\eqref{q-def} defines vector $\vc{q}$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or as matrix without commas:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\transpose}{\mathrm{T}}
\newcommand*{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{q-def}
  \vc{q} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mu_1 & \mu_2 & \dots & \mu_{n-1} & \mu_{n}
    \end{pmatrix}^\transpose
\end{equation}
Equation~\eqref{q-def} defines vector $\vc{q}$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result as matrix]

### Second question

The equation can be typeset as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  L = \log(l) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \bigl(
    \log (
      \mathbf{s}(\exp \{ \mathbf{Q} t_i\})
      \mathbf{q}
    )
  \bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for second question]

Comment: May be `\renewcommand*\vec{\mathbf}` and use `\vec{q}`.

Comment: @Manuel `\vec` and `\vector` are already defined, thus I have updated the answer using `\vc`. I have kept `\mahbf` for the second question, because it is not too clear, if these are vectors, matrices, or tensors.

Answer (score 3):

you should really have posted these as two separate questions, instead of adding on to the first.  but you could try

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{q}=(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots ,\mu_{n-2}, \mu_n )^{\text{T}} \label{2} 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    L = \log(l) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\left( \log(s(\exp\left\{\mathbf{Q}_{i}^{t}\right\})\mathbf{q}) \right)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: equations]

Comment: oh, if that's not supposed to be a superscript t, then drop it inline...the picture looks a little fuzzy to me so at first i thought you wanted a superscript there.  but i would encourage use of parentheses and curly braces that scale.

Comment: yes I did that  :) would it be possible to help me with the matrix I just posted? I am a beginner and really appreciate as they were taking me a lot of time!

Comment: using `\left` and `\right` on the braces around the `Q` expression results in braces that are larger than the next-surrounding parentheses, which looks bad.  the extra size isn't really needed though, so the answer is *not* to add more `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton in the case that i (accidentally) typeset, without `\left` and `\right` creates braces that do not fully encompass the superscript and subscript.  so should the answer actually have been to use `\left` and `\right` with the next-surrounding parentheses as well?

Comment: @aeroNotAuto -- if you use `\left` and `\right` on the next pair, then you'd have to continue, and the result would be that the outermost pair would be entirely too large.  better to take a little more time, use `\bigl`/`\bigr` and friends, and keep them as size-restricted as possible.  there are many questions on this site with sensible guidance regarding sizing of delimiters, including when to let sub/superscripts and limits "hang out".